# awesome_nested_fields how create a nested form for nested model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using awesome_nested_fields gem for create nice and simple nested fields forms.

My problem is the next. I have a model called `Product`. This `has_many :variants`. These variants `has_many :item_properties, :as => :propertiable`

How could create a form for item_properties fields if these belongs to variants (And the form is for products)

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english and if you need more code or information please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is too late, but anyways. Take look at that wiki page https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields/wiki/Multi-level-Nested-Fields